# Campsis is growing very slowly with holes in the leaves

Tags: leaves, growth, vines

We purchased our red Campsis Radicans in the beginning of May which is depicted below. This picture was taken today. What surprizes me is that many articles claim that Campsis is a fast growing vine so I think something is wrong with ours. Specifically:

1. Within 2 months it only gave several new short shoots.
2. Many leaves have holes in it. We can't find out which insect might cause those holes.

It is planted in 30cm tall pot with multi-purpose peat based compost (the only compost we could find online at that time). We never fed it with any fertilizer and keep watering it 2-3 times per week. Could you suggest what are we doing wrong with it?

[image: Campsis Radicans]

Answer (score 0):

After continuous watering, and adding some used coffee grounds the plant revived and vines started growing. Maybe it was asleep in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Campis is a vigorous climber. Can't you plant it in the ground somewhere suitable? More information [here](https://www.rhs.org.uk/plants/2993/i-campsis-radicans-i/details).